# Getting multiple if statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm making an interactive series for my school project. We have some voice overs on the video's. So we have male and female voices. So I made a page with a button where they can choose between a male (man) and female(vrouw). the first if statement works like a charm. ( choosing between a male and female voice) after this, the user can choose between 2 choices in the video. But "choiceaman" doesn't work at all. Anyone an idea how I can make it work better. (FYI I'm not a coder usually so this is all new for me)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            if ($.cookie('keuzemanvrouw') == "man") {
                $("#pilotman").show();
                $("#pilotvrouw").hide();
                $("#choiceavrouw").hide();
                $("#choicebvrouw").hide();
                $("#choiceaman").hide();
                $("#choicebman").hide();
                $("#keuzemanvrouw").hide();
            }

            else if ($.cookie('keuzemanvrouw') == "vrouw") {
                $("#pilotvrouw").show();
                $("#pilotman").hide();
                $("#choiceaman").hide();
                $("#choicebman").hide();
                $("#choiceavrouw").hide();
                $("#choicebvrouw").hide();
                $("#keuzemanvrouw").hide();

            } else if ($.cookie('choice1') == "choiceaman"){
                $("#choiceaman").show();
                $("#choicebman").hide();
                $("#pilotman").hide();
            }

            else if ($.cookie('choice1') == "choiceavrouw"){
                $("#choiceavrouw").show();
                $("#choicebvrouw").hide();
                $("#pilotvrouw").hide();
            }


            else if ($.cookie('choice1') == "choiceman"){
                $("#choicebman").show();
                $("#choiceaman").hide();
                $("#pilotman").hide();
            }



            else {
                $("#pilotvrouw").hide();
                $("#pilotman").hide();
                $("#choiceavrouw").hide();
                $("#choiceaman").hide();
                $("#choicebvrouw").hide();
                $("#choicebman").hide();
            }
        });
```

Comment: @PaulCrovella this is the script running on the page

Comment: @TimRoering and it has nothing to do with PHP :)

Comment: After choosing between Men or Women your if sentece stops, so for choice1 cookie create a new if sentence.

Comment: thats jquerry, right?:o

Comment: Use common class like `man,vrouw......` instead of  multiple `id's` and then do the `if-else`.code will become short and more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($.cookie('keuzemanvrouw') == "man" || $.cookie('keuzemanvrouw') == "vrouw" || $.cookie('choice1') == "choiceaman" || $.cookie('choice1') == "choiceavrouw") {

        if ($.cookie('keuzemanvrouw') == "man") {
            $("#pilotman").show();
            $("#pilotvrouw").hide();
            $("#choiceavrouw").hide();
            $("#choicebvrouw").hide();
            $("#choiceaman").hide();
            $("#choicebman").hide();
            $("#keuzemanvrouw").hide();
        } else if ($.cookie('keuzemanvrouw') == "vrouw") {
            $("#pilotvrouw").show();
            $("#pilotman").hide();
            $("#choiceaman").hide();
            $("#choicebman").hide();
            $("#choiceavrouw").hide();
            $("#choicebvrouw").hide();
            $("#keuzemanvrouw").hide();

        }

        if ($.cookie('choice1') == "choiceaman") {
            $("#choiceaman").show();
            $("#choicebman").hide();
            $("#pilotman").hide();
        } else if ($.cookie('choice1') == "choiceavrouw") {
            $("#choiceavrouw").show();
            $("#choicebvrouw").hide();
            $("#pilotvrouw").hide();
        }

    } else {
        $("#pilotvrouw").hide();
        $("#pilotman").hide();
        $("#choiceavrouw").hide();
        $("#choiceaman").hide();
        $("#choicebvrouw").hide();
        $("#choicebman").hide();
    }
});
```

Your `if` statements are all hanging off each other, so the `choice1` cookie `else if`s won't run if `keuzemanvrouw` is `man` or `vrouw`. `else if`s only run if there are no other previous if statements that fired.

Think of it like this:

```
if (false) { // Does check this statement.
    // Doesn't run this code.
} else if (true) { // Does check this statement.
    // Runs this code.
} else if (true) { // Doesn't check this statement, because the previous one worked.
    // Doesn't run this code.
}
```

Comment: No problem @TimRoering , happy to help :) Be sure to read this wiki page on [what to do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Already  tried to accept it  but can't for another minute haha :)

Comment: @TimRoering Haha, that's alright :) Although you do have the [voting privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) now, so be sure to try that out ;)